# Where can we use Cross Apply and Outer Apply instead of Inner and outer join

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am familiar in the joining concepts but i recently known the APPLY concepts.I am really confused with this concept please tell me where can we use the concepts.

Comment: This is called a "lateral join" in the SQL standard (I have no idea why Microsoft ignored that). Maybe searching for that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try these two articles.

[Understanding and Using APPLY (Part 1)](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/APPLY/69953/)

[Understanding and Using APPLY (Part 2)](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/APPLY/69954/)